# how to aggregate results and create arrays on certain fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and not sure where to begin with this.

Here is my data in ES:

```
[{
  product_id: "xxxyyyxx",
  shop_id: "shop1",
  name: "Elastic testing",
  creator: "Test 1337",
  price: 13
},
{
  product_id: "xxxyyyxx",
  shop_id: "shop2",
  name: "Elastic testing",
  creator: "Test 1337",
  price: 10
}]
```

What I want to get

```
{
  product_id: "xxxyyyxx",
  shops: ['shop1', 'shop2'],
  name: "Elastic testing",
  creator: "Test 1337",
  min_price: 10,
  max_price: 13
}
```

Here is what I have so far, which only returns the results without aggregation...

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
    query: 'test',
    fields: ['creator', 'name', 'info']
  }
}
```

if you can point me in the right direction of where to start, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).
There a aggregations that group your data into so called [buckets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html), and aggregations that you can use on that buckets to calculate [metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html). An example for metric would be your need for min and max price. You can nest aggregations, to get your desired result.

Aggregations are defined outside of the query, the matches for your query are used as input data.

In your usecase, you could use a terms aggregation on the name field, this will provide you with a bucket for every name. If you then use a metric for max and min on this bucket you already have a part of the desired result.

Regarding the shopIds,you will need to nest another bucket aggregation which will provide you with a bucket for every single value of the fiels shopId containing all documents with that value.

Example:

```
"query": { //your query here ...},
    "aggs" : {
        "name_term" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
            "aggs" : {
                "max_price" : { "max" : { "field" : "price" } },
                "min_price" : { "min" : { "field" : "price" } },
                "shops" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "shop_id" }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, do you have any ideas about creating the array of shop id's?

Comment: sure! i have added it to my answer.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. I'm getting an error when I'm trying to just run the aggs on a single field "creator" `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [creator] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.` can you provide an example mapping also? Much appreciated for all your help :-)

Comment: could u provide me with your query? It seems like you try to aggregate on creator which is a full text search field (those are analyzed, meens the values are stored in splitted terms in the inverted index). If you want to aggregate on a field it is better to use the keyword mapping for it.

Comment: I want to aggregate on multiple fields, e.g. product_id, creator, name & info and have the shop_ids in an array and a min and max price. I just tried to test on doing it with creator first without a query e.g. `aggs: { products: { terms: { field: 'creator' } } }`

Comment: I was able to get it to work for the most part, just not the shop_id's into an array. But using agg `top_hits` returns the source of each record so I can loop through those to produce my array. Thanks very much for your help. You definitely lightened my elasticsearch learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

creating an array of ids is declared the same as declaring a normal field:

```
"product_id": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "store": "true",
    "index": "true"
}
```

Just make sure that your array is named as product_id in your class:

```
List<String> product_id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to get an array of id's from an aggregation of queried documents. Can you please expand on your answer.